# Logback with logstash-logback-encoder not working

Tags: java, servlets, logging, logback, logstash

I am having problems using Logback with the logstash-logback-encoder.

My logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="stash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <file>logs/development.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>logs/development.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
  </appender>
  <root level="all">
    <appender-ref ref="stash" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I tried to create a logs/development in my project home:

[image]

For some reason it won't write to the log file.

I tried to add:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "logs/development.log"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
```

But I don't know where to add this in my project so that logStash will recognize it.

The logging works if I delete the file "logback.xml", so logging actually happens, but it is not stored in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly improbable that logback will kindly log to `src/main/resources/logs/development.log` You should rather try to see if another `development.log` file is not created somewhere else in your project (for example in target, or if you run the project into another environment such as a server tomcat, look for the deployment directory)

Once you have confirmed which file actually get the logs, you can try to configure logstash, which you must run as a separate program.  As a consequence, the configuration for logstash takes place nowhere in your project. Or maybe you could run it in a separate project, but it is kinda weird. I personally always run it directly from the command line.

Hope this helps